# How to use AWS CLI to edit s3 bucket metadata to add Cache-Control header in that?

Tags: amazon-web-services, caching, amazon-s3, cache-control

Can someone provide me with the command for metadata, so that i can add cache-control header to all the objects within my s3 bucket ?

I have already read an article about s3cmd, and to do this task with s3cmd i got one command -

```
./s3cmd --recursive modify --add-header="Cache-Control:public ,max-age= 31536000" s3://your_bucket_name/
```

But, for encryption purpose this  `s3cmd` requires to install GNU. So, it is not free. That's why i want to use s3 CLI.

Comment: Making a comment as this isn't an answer but a suggestion.
You should serve your s3 files via a Cloudfront distribution.
Cloudfront is a much better way to control the caching life-cycle of your files and will provide better performance

Comment: hi  @John , i have already tried a way of adding cache behaviour in cloudfront distribution with specifying min, max, default TTL, but i still have "expiration not specified" warning in pagespeed insights. That means cache control/ expiry for cashing is not getting applied to objects and that is what i am unable to resolve. So, i was searching for adding cache-header/expires header to all objects at a time.  Can you please tell me, what should be settings for my cloudfront cache distribution then ?

Comment: The advice from @John is incomplete. CloudFront is a good idea, but you do need to set this on your S3 objects as well, for the benefit of the browser.

Comment: From memory... I believe it will be something like `aws s3 cp s3://bucket/key s3://bucket/key --metadata-directive COPY --cache-control '...desired value...'`... essentially copying the object onto itself.  Will have to verify this before I can say for certain.

Comment: @Michael yes thanks, for memory/disk caching

For an entire bucket, we can use :       

aws s3 cp s3://mybucket/ s3://mybucket/ --recursive --metadata-directive REPLACE --expires 2034-01-01T00:00:00Z --acl public-read --cache-control max-age=2592000,public

                .......................I have used this now and it successfully worked out....